# Completar formulario con json jquery, sin base de datos

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsonp

Pregunta: podrian facilitarme un ejemplo para completar un formulario con un arreglo de json, la idea es presindir de una base de datos. Solo se debe ingresar el codigo del cliente, y el nombre y direccion deberia autocompletarse.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mil gracias por anticipado.

Comment: que has intentado?

Comment: Hola Tato te invito a revisar [ask] y [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Si solo es de ejemplo:

```js
function buscarAjax(){
  var url='data.php';// Aquí va la ruta de consulta, la cual te devolvería en JSON
  var cod=$("#codigo").val()';// El id del campo código
  $.ajax({
    url:url,
    type:'GET',
    data:{id:cod},
    success: function(r){
      $("#nombre").val(r.nombre);
      $("#direccion").val(r.direccion);
    }
  });
}
// En 'data', en el 'id' deberas poner el nombre del como recives el parámetro  en 'data.php'
// El JSON que te devuelva 'data.php' debe tener forma {"nombre":"pepe","direccion":"botella s/n 2° c"}
```

```html
<a class='btn btn-primary' href='#' onclick='buscarAjax()'>Buscar</a>
```

Comment: se te agradece la intención, pero noes bien visto en la comunidad responder a preguntas mal planteadas que solo piden, pero no muestran avance alguno